# Ubuntu 18.04 boot error: syntax error :unexpected end of file when loading .profile

Tags: boot, login, .profile

I am unable to do anything after this dialog box appears:

```
/home/hp/.profile: line 31:syntax error :unexpected end of file
As a result the session will not be configured correctly. You should fix the problem as soon as feasible.
```

Answer (score 0):

I see, only 2 possibilites.

[boot in to recovery mode](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode)

and rename the file.

```
mv /home/hp/.profile /home/hp/.profile.broken
```

Or, you boot any Live-Linux  and make the renaming from there.
For that you have to mount the filesystem.You can get an overview with

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

If you have only one partition/filesystem on you harddrive, then you have to mount them. 
Easiest way, is to use the file-manager.
with

```
sudo lsblk -f
```

You can see there it is mounted.

```
sudo mv /fullpath/to/home/hp/.profile /full/path/to/home/hp/.profile.broken
```

Please use TAB key for autocomplete